# How to append query string in every action url in .net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, query-string

I want to append a query string in every action URL in the .net core application.

eg:

```
https://localhost:44329/Account/EventPreview?preview=4175
```

is my current request.

```
https://localhost:44329/Home
```

after appending the query string it should be

```
https://localhost:44329/Home?preview=4175
```

and similarly

```
https://localhost:44329/Account/CreatePassword?Id=21 => 
https://localhost:44329/Account/CreatePassword?Id=21&preview=4175
```

I tried to append a query string in the `OnActionExecuting` method by using this code:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    int preview = HtmlHelperExtensions.GetIntSessionValue(SessionKey.Preview.ToString());

    if (preview > 0)
    {
        string longurl = $"{filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Scheme}://{filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Host}{filterContext.HttpContext.Request.PathBase}{filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Path}{filterContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString}";
        var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(longurl);
        var query = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uriBuilder.Query);
        query.Add("preview", preview.ToString());
        uriBuilder.Query = query.ToString();
        longurl = uriBuilder.ToString();

        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString.HasValue || (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString.HasValue && !filterContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString.Value.Contains("preview")))
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(longurl);
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried using `app.Use` method in `Startup.cs` file. The query string will append in URL but can't get as `HttpContext.Request.QueryString` value in `Startup.cs` file.

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            var url = context.Request.GetEncodedUrl();
           
            //// Rewrite privacy URL to index
            if (context.Request.QueryString.HasValue)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request.Query["preview"]))
                {
                    //context.Request.Query["preview"] = "4175";                        
                    context.Request.QueryString.Add(QueryString.Create("preview", "4175"));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                context.Request.QueryString.Add(QueryString.Create("preview", "4175"));
            }

            //context.Request.Path = "";
            await next();
        });
```

I achieved to modify URL by adding query string in my ASP.NET MVC application using `Application_BeginRequest()` method in the `Global.asax.cs` file.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-1));
    Response.Cache.SetNoStore();

    HttpContext context = base.Context;

    #region ForQueryStringPrevent
    var oHttpApplication = (HttpApplication)sender;
    var oPathAndQuery = oHttpApplication.Context.Request.Url.PathAndQuery;

    if (oPathAndQuery.Contains("?" + HtmlHelperExtension.Encrypt("Alliant=")))
    {
        var NewoPathAndQuery = oPathAndQuery.Split(new string[] { "?" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        var oPath = NewoPathAndQuery[0];
        var oQueryString = NewoPathAndQuery[1].Replace(HtmlHelperExtension.Encrypt("Alliant="), "");
        var oDecodedURL = HtmlHelperExtension.Decrypt(oQueryString.ToString());
        oHttpApplication.Context.RewritePath(oPath + "?" + oDecodedURL.ToString());
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Can anyone please help me with this? Is there any way to append query string as I did in the ASP.NET MVC application?

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info). Can you explain what you are trying to achieve with this? Why not use a cookie?

Comment: If you are planning to append query string for each request then you can try with Middlewares.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: Hello @Xerillio, I want to use query string in the `Startup.cs` file. The main problem is cookies and session variables can not be accessible in the `Startup.cs` file. I edited the above question. Can you please check that?

Comment: @HarviPatel Try to forget the fact that there's something called a "query string". Then try to explain what problem you are actually trying to solve. (Why do you need this query parameter?)

Comment: I want to set the connection string for the preview site based on the URL. There are multiple databases in my application.

Comment: So, to rephrase your question; You're trying to implement a multi-tenant web app. And you wish to solve this problem with a global route parameter. Ensuring that all generated links pass this value between pages.

Comment: Hello @JeremyLakeman, You are absolutely correct.

Comment: Since ambient route values are preserved left-to-right (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#url-generation-process), defining a controller template like "{preview}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}" might "just work". For razor pages or query parameters, I don't know if there's an easy solution.

Comment: Hello @JeremyLakeman, I tried custom routing as per your suggestion. But It didn't work for me.